# make button in html delete a row in MySql

Tags: html, mysql, node.js

i am currently working on a project where i use nodejs to make a user that adds users to MySql in a table called "users"
i would like to make a button in html which deletes the currently logged in user from the mysql table

how do i make a button in html call a function in nodejs which deletes a Row in MySql

Answer (score 0):

This may be a good start to understand how to trigger API calls from Js

```
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/deleteUser', {
    method: "DELETE",
    headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
       id: '1'
    })
})
.then(res => {
    if (res.ok) { console.log("HTTP request successful") }
    else { console.log("HTTP request unsuccessful") }
    return res
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.log(error))
```

And then for NodeJs

```
// Module dependencies

var express    = require('express'),
    ejs        = require('ejs'),
    fs         = require('fs'),
    mysql      = require('mysql');

// Application initialization

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : '' //<your password
    });
    
var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Database setup

connection.query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    connection.query('USE test', function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        connection.query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users('
            + 'id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,'
            + 'PRIMARY KEY(id),'
            + 'name VARCHAR(30)'
            +  ')', function (err) {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
    });
});

// Configuration

app.use(express.bodyParser());

// Post delete user
app.post('/deleteUser', function(req, res) {
var id=Number(req.query.id);
console.log(id);
connection.query('delete from users where id='+id,
});
```